# How to show that sequence $n\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ has no convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Question:** How to show that the sequence $n\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ has no convergent subsequence or in general how to show that sequence has no convergent subsequence.

**My attempt**: If the sequence is bounded then it has a convergent subsequence by Bolzano Weierstrass theorem but, when sequence is not bounded then it may or may not have convergent subsequence! For example: The sequence $1,2,3,1,4,5,1,6,7,1,…$ is Not bounded but has convergent subsequence, which is the constant sequence $1,1,1,…$

But here, in the case of the sequence given in the question,I am unable to determine it is bounded or not and it has convergent subsequence or Not! Please help me…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $n\cos(1/n) > n/2$ for all $n$ large enough. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sir, sorry but how you came up with that inequality? Further by that inequality we can’t determine that sequence has convergent subsequence or not! Because unbounded sequence may have convergent subsequences

Comment: @GeneralMathematics $\cos(1/n)\ge \cos(1/1)>1/2$ since $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @Gary sir thank you. Now I get that how that inequality come but from that inequality how to determine that sequence has no convergent subsequence?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics Note that your sequence is strictly increasing and tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I got it. I have used a contradiction method. Suppose that sequence $(n\cos(\frac{1}{n}))$ has convergent subsequence say, $(n_{k}\cos(\frac{1}{n_k}))$.  But this subsequence diverges to infinity as k tends to infinity and hence we get contradiction!